# How to make a table's style like jquery grid(jqgrid)?

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid, grid

I have generate a table in html frontend.
Then I have to change the table's style to jqgrid style for matching other system.
How could I do for these? ,what css files should I link to my page?
and How to add class to my table.
I have just need the jqgrid style and the function that the column can be strech to match longer words in table's cell

Answer (score 0):

You realy can't apply just one jqgrid class to your table becouse jqgrid add some thicky html structure for it's needs. But jqgrid api have [function](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:table_to_jqgrid) `tableToGrid`. So you can easily apply it to your table like this:

```
tableToGrid("#your-table");
```

Also there are `options` in this function that you can use to your table. Even pager and client side searching with it:

```
tableToGrid("#your-table", {
        autowidth:true,
        pager: '#pager',
        rowNum: 20,
        viewrecords: true,
        loadui: true,
        rowList: [10,20,50]
    });
```